# Pressing Alt+F4 keys using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating an application using selenium webdriver. There is a modal window in my application on which we cannot do any action or handle it. we just have to close the window. The only option we have is pressing Alt+F4 key to close the window.I have the below code to do those actions which is not working. Please let me know how to achieve this

Code:

`Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.keyDown(Keys.ALT);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.F4);
        actions.keyUp(Keys.ALT);
        actions.perform();`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using the following code

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
```

To get this code running you need to add,
    import java.awt.Robot;

Answer (score 0):

You can use "driver.close". It will close the current active window.

Answer (score 0):

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someXpath']")).click(); // click some link that opens a new window

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
}

//code to do something on new window

driver.close(); // close newly opened window when done with it
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); // switch back to the original window
```

Hope it works for you :)